# Using reflection to populate a pointer to a struct

Tags: go, reflection

I'd like to iterate over the fields in a struct and prompt for string values to string fields, doing this recursively for fields that are pointers to structs.

Currently this is what I've tried, but I get an error when trying to set this value in the pointer's string field.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Table struct {
    PK *Field
}

type Field struct {
    Name string
}


func main() {
    PopulateStruct(&Table{})
}

func PopulateStruct(a interface{}) interface {} {
    typeOf := reflect.TypeOf(a)
    valueOf := reflect.ValueOf(a)
    for i := 0; i < typeOf.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
        switch typeOf.Elem().Field(i).Type.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            fmt.Print(typeOf.Elem().Field(i).Name)
            var s string
            fmt.Scanf("%s", &s)
            valueOf.Elem().Field(i).SetString(s)
        case reflect.Ptr:
            ptr := reflect.New(valueOf.Elem().Field(i).Type())
            PopulateStruct(ptr.Elem().Interface())
            valueOf.Elem().Field(i).Set(ptr)
        }
    }
}
```

Expecting the return value to include an initialised struct with the pointers string field set.

Getting an error when setting the pointer's string field.

panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.Field on zero Value

Comment: Is the pointer `nil`? If so, you'll need to initialize it with a value before traversing into it.

Comment: Update the question to show your test case.

Answer (score 3):

I dropped your code as-is into the Go Playground and it doesn't build because `PopulateStruct` is declared as returning `interface{}` but does not actually return anything.  Removing the declared return type produces the panic you mention.

This is because at entry to the outer `PopulateStruct` call, you have a valid pointer, pointing to a zero-valued `Table`.  A zero-valued `Table` has one element: a nil pointer in it of type `*Field`.  Your loop therefore runs once and finds a `reflect.Ptr`, as you expected.  Adding more diagnostic print messages helps see what's happening:

```
fmt.Printf("PopulateStruct: I have typeOf=%v, valueOf=%v\n", typeOf, valueOf)
for i := 0; i < typeOf.Elem().NumField(); i++ {
    switch typeOf.Elem().Field(i).Type.Kind() {
// ... snipped some code ...
    case reflect.Ptr:
        ptr := reflect.New(valueOf.Elem().Field(i).Type())
        fmt.Println("after allocating ptr, we have:", ptr.Type(), ptr,
            "but its Elem is:", ptr.Elem().Type(), ptr.Elem())
```

This prints:

```
PopulateStruct: I have typeOf=*main.Table, valueOf=&{<nil>}
after allocating ptr, we have: **main.Field 0x40c138 but its Elem is: *main.Field <nil>
```

Given the way `PopulateStruct` itself is constructed, we must actually allocate a real `Field` instance *now*, before calling `PopulateStruct`.  We can do this with:

```
        p2 := ptr.Elem()
        ptr.Elem().Set(reflect.New(p2.Type().Elem()))
```

([code borrowed from `json.Unmarshal`](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/decode.go?s#L474)).  Now we can fill in this `Field`, which has one field named `Name` of type `String`.

The overall strategy here is not that great, in my opinion: filling-in probably should take a generic pointer, not specifically a pointer-to-`struct` pointer.  You can then emulate the `indirect` function in the json unmarshaller.  However, the addition of these two lines—creating the target object and making the allocated pointer point to it—suffices to make your existing code run.

(Alternatively, you could just create and return a whole instance from scratch, in which case all you need is the type—but I'm assuming you have a pattern in which only *some* fields are nil.)

[Here's the complete Go Playground example.](https://play.golang.org/p/i8c5JlXFwp5)  I made a few other changes as there's nothing to scan from when using the playground.